# Python Web Scraping : How to use Selenium to Scraping Data Real-Time didn't refresh Web

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working my project to get data real-time on [Web](https://www.tmd.go.th/en/) but if I don't want to use `driver.refresh()`,how to scraping data Real-time?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
Data =[]
num =0
url = 'https://www.tmd.go.th/en/'
while num<2:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/span').text
    Data.append(temp)
    print(Data)
    driver.refresh()
    num+=1
else:
    print('finish')
```

This image is result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4S6J.png)
Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: is there a datetime telling us when the temperature value was updated?